# Logarithmic colorbar on map using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I am attempting to recreate a figure that has a symmetrical colorbar that doubles each value for each tick mark (i.e. 0, 20, 40, 80, 160, 320, etc.) I have tried using `norm=colors.LogNorm(vmin=-480, vmax=480)` but now my colorbar only consists of six colors and most of my ticks are bunched up together towards the ends of the colorbar.

How can I fix this so that I have 14 different colors on my colorbar and the ticks spaced out more evenly/accurately?

Also, this is my code:

```py
fig, axs = pplt.subplots(ncols = 2, nrows = 1, axwidth = 7, proj='pcarree')
ax1, ax2 = axs
tick_vals = [-480, -320, -160, -80, -40, -20, 0, 20, 40, 80, 160, 320, 480]

norm = colors.SymLogNorm(linthresh=20, linscale=1, vmin=min(tick_vals), vmax=max(tick_vals))

a = ax1.contourf(era_cape['lon'], era_cape['lat'], regression, norm = norm, cmap = cmap, add_colorbar = False, extend = 'both')
ax2.contourf(reg_cesm['lon'], reg_cesm['lat'], reg_le, norm = norm, cmap = cmap, add_colorbar = False, extend = 'both')
cbar = fig.colorbar(a, loc="bottom", cmap = cmap,  labelsize= 14, shrink = 1, ticks = tick_vals)
```

Comment: `LogNorm` only works for strictly positive values. Maybe you want `SymLogNorm`, which has converts positive and negative numbers separately (and has a short linear connecting piece in-between).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

SymLogNorm

- Pros: Suitable for symmetric data, maintains linear scaling near zero.
- Cons: Linear scaling can result in non-precise tick multiples, less intuitive for negative values.

LogNorm

- Pros: Adapts well to wide-ranging data, maintains proportional relationships between values.
- Cons: Hard to find exact ticks that match desired multiples, less suitable for negative values.

For your problem I recommend using SymLogNorm, the following is the sample code:

```
# Generate some sample data (replace this with your actual data)
data = np.random.randint(-480, 480, size=(10, 10))

# Define the tick values you're interested in
tick_values = [-480, -320, -160, -80, -40, -20, 0, 20, 40, 80, 160, 320, 480]

# Create a symmetric logarithmic normalization
norm = SymLogNorm(linthresh=20, linscale=1, vmin=min(tick_values), vmax=max(tick_values))

# Create a figure and axis
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Create the heatmap
heatmap = ax.imshow(data, cmap='RdBu_r', norm=norm)

# Add a colorbar
cbar = plt.colorbar(heatmap, ax=ax, ticks=tick_values)
cbar.set_label('Colorbar Label')

plt.show()
```

Comment: You have not checked _"your"_ code. I have, and it's unable to fulfill OP's requirements.